# How to get list of html content of all the elements having a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I am trying (jquery):

```
var lis = $('.options.high');
for (var i = 0; i<lis.length; i++){
    console.log(lis[i].html());
}
```

but this is not allowed I believe. Please suggest some alternative.

**Update:** Resolved. It was quite silly question. Please ignore.

Comment: Try `$('.options.high').each()` - **[.each()](http://api.jquery.com/each/)**. `.html()` wont work on array object.

Comment: Try  `console.log($(lis[i]).html());`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**.each()**](http://api.jquery.com/each/) in jquery for this

```
$('options.high').each(function () {
    alert($(this).html());
});
```

Note: Remove the `.` before `options`, if it is not the class name.

Answer (score 2):

`.html()` is method for jQuery objects. Wrap `lis[i]` like this

```
$(lis[i]).html()
```

JS :

```
var lis = $('.options.high');
for (var i = 0; i<lis.length; i++){
    console.log($(lis[i]).html());
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bxV5W/)**

A preferable way is to use `.each()`.

```
var lis = $('.options.high');
lis.each(function(index){
    console.log($(this).html());   //OR $(lis[index]).html()
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bxV5W/1/)**